# How to setup a code coverage for selenium+java based framework using Istanbul

Tags: selenium-webdriver, istanbul

I want to check the code coverage for my automation tests.I Need to use Istanbul to check the code coverage.Please help me if you guys have the steps to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please mention what steps/code you've followed/written and if you faced with any issue/failure? Merely stating 'I need to achieve XXX' is not a great way to get concise answers.

Comment: I want step by step procedure to check the selenium test code coverage using Istanbul. Like how to add Istanbul dependency and how to instrument, etc.

Comment: What steps have you implemented?

Comment: Need to start freshly.I didn't get the procedure or videos anywhere.